# Smart GWT - change text color of clicked record in ListGrid

Tags: record, smartgwt, listgrid

I'm using Smart GWT version 4. I want to change the text color of selected record on record click action. I cannot find a way to do it using "setHilites" method or anything else. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go by the BaseStyle way, its something like this.

```
    @Override
protected String getBaseStyle(ListGridRecord record, int rowNum, int colNum){

    if (listGrid.getSelectedRecord() == record){
        return "custom-color-CSS";
    }

    return super.getBaseStyle(record, rowNum, colNum);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in a ListGrid.getCellCSSText or ListGrid.getBaseStyle method, you could use the ListGrid.isSelected(record) to return appropriate style.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have tried above methods, but had no luck. both the ListGrid.getCellCSSText method and ListGrid.getBaseStyle method returns null for me. Anyways I think another way to achieve this requirement is to set a hilte to the grid. Is there a way to set a set hilite to a list grid inside on record click action ? I have tried out calling "Listgrid.setHilites("hilite_name");" at a click handler of the List grid. But its not getting effected.

Comment: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear: you have to implemente the getBaseStyle or getCellCSSText method, as in these samples:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_hilite_add
and 
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_hilite_replace